# how can i send filebeat output to logstash via udp protocol?

Tags: logging, logstash, filebeat, elk

is there any way to send data from filebeat to logstash via udp protocol, I configured logstash to receive data from udp, can i do the same with filebeat.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: is there any way to send data from filebeat to logstash via udp protocol?

No, Filebeat can not send events over UDP. Here are all the available Filebeat outputs:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-output.html

Filebeat can only **read** events over UDP as described here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-input-udp.html

Furthermore, here are some answers to identical questions that come to the same result:

- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/could-filebeat-use-udp-to-send-data-to-logstash/113527
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-configure-filebeat-to-send-logs-over-udp-to-graylog/130822

I hope I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Filebeat doesn't support UDP output. However, you can send data to logstash with the logstash output module available in the Filebeat yml file.

If you are very sure of using UDP only, you can use nxlog instead of forget, which supports a UDP output. It is also more flexible than Filebeat for patterns and filters with regular expressions from the source itself.

Hope this helps!